# Variables in /etc/resolver/ for domain specific DNS on MacOS

Tags: macos, dns

I have a growing list of files in /etc/resolver for domain specific DNS resolvers. Each resolver is using the same nameserver and all other traffic is using my router defined DNS. Currently, if I want to change the custom DNS nameserver I have to change multiple files.

Does anyone know of a way to set a variable to the nameserver IP and then call that variable inside each resolver file?